# MySQL: Making 2 values unique

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, 2d, coordinates

I'm trying to make 2 values unique, like if I have the values (5, 10) the same values can't be added again.

I'm currently selecting from the table the values x and y, checking if they both together exists on the table if they don't exists insert them, in other words

"Select * from location where x=? and y=?"

if no result is returned it will continue to insert the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically accomplished by creating a unique index on both columns combined (a multi-column index).

Then, MySQL will prevent you from inserting duplicates. You can go ahead and try to insert the record, and if you get a duplicate key error, you know it already exists.

Alternatively, another way to handle it is to use `INSERT IGNORE`, so that no error occurs if you try to insert a duplicate row. Still, it won't insert, so you simply check the affected `ROW_COUNT()` to see if the insert was successful.

Using a unique index and catching the failure on the insert is more performant than selecting then trying to insert because in the case you do insert, MySQL only has to perform one search, rather than two.